# Choosing Restore Date in Carbon Copy Cloner

Tags: backup

Using CCC, how do I restore my El Capitan OS system to a date of several days ago.  I installed a flakey app. and I want to essentially backdate my system to before I installed it.  Everything I can find re restoring with CCC seems to restore to the last backup.  I don't want that; I want to restore to an earlier date.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There actually are no earlier dates. CCC creates snapshots/clone images of your hard drive, it doesn't create versions.

Comment: Marc: Interesting info, but no help.  How do I restore my Mac to its configuration other than the last backup done by CCC?

Comment: In order to restore to an earlier date, you have to have an earlier backup.  If you do not have one, you can reinstall the OS from OS X Recovery.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314